# Using Countif with criteria a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Is it possible to user countifs with criteria being a range of cells

Can I do this?

```
=COUNTIFS(G1:G14989,'Data-Update'!B40:B41)
```

My criteria do not follow any set of rules to work based on, its not a date or a number, it's names.

Comment: If there are only two cells in the criteria part of the COUNTIFS, might be easier to split into 2 countif's?

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough this can be accomplished with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(range1,range2))
```